# RxSwift - Emit after not receiving items for X seconds

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

I have been trying to figure out a way to implement such behavior but was not able to come to a working solution.

**What I want to achieve**

```
var dataSource = Variable<[T]>([])

var arrayObserver: Observable<SomeType> {

    return dataSource.asObservable()
        .map({ (elementoftype[T]) in

        // do something with it and return element of SomeType
        })
}
```

The `dataSource` variable is fed with values coming in 1 by 1. I want the `arrayObserver` to be able to buffer / "hold" onto the `map`ping until it has been, say, 0.5 seconds since the `dataSource` last emitted.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out calling

```
.throttle(0.5, MainScheduler.instance)
```

before mapping does the job.

Comment: It looks like it is .debounce(...) function you actually want